# Break long table rows into multiple lines in documentation

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I want to document my crate and include a table in the documentation:

```rust
//! Demonstrating MarkDown tables.
//!
//! | Foo | Bar | Baz | Qux |
//! | --- | --- | --- | --- |
//! | Hail the turbofish `::<>` | Ferris for president  | I can't think of any more "funny" things | oopsie |
//!
```

Rendering this with `cargo doc` results in:

[image: correct table]

This is what I want. However, you might have noticed that the one source code line is very long. In fact, over 100 characters long. Like many Rust projects, I want to keep all my lines under 100 characters long. So I tried to break the line somehow.

All of these versions:

```
//! | Foo | Bar | Baz | Qux |
//! | --- | --- | --- | --- |
//! | Hail the turbofish `::<>` | Ferris for president  
//! I can't think of any more "funny" things | oopsie |

//! | Foo | Bar | Baz | Qux |
//! | --- | --- | --- | --- |
//! | Hail the turbofish `::<>` | Ferris for president  |
//! I can't think of any more "funny" things | oopsie |

//! | Foo | Bar | Baz | Qux |
//! | --- | --- | --- | --- |
//! | Hail the turbofish `::<>` | Ferris for president 
//! | I can't think of any more "funny" things | oopsie |

//! | Foo | Bar | Baz | Qux |
//! | --- | --- | --- | --- |
//! | Hail the turbofish `::<>` | Ferris for president  |
//! | I can't think of any more "funny" things | oopsie |

//! | Foo | Bar | Baz | Qux |
//! | --- | --- | --- | --- |
//! | Hail the turbofish `::<>` | Ferris for president  \
//! I can't think of any more "funny" things | oopsie |
```

Results in:

[image]

**What options do I have to include long table rows in my documentation without violating the line length limit?**

Comment: rustdoc utilizes [pulldown-cmark](https://github.com/raphlinus/pulldown-cmark) and there's no support for what you want. You have to use HTML as already answered. Or a) create separate `.md` files, prepare `build.rs` to convert `.md` -> `.rs` file (prepend `//!` or `///`) and use `include!`, b) wait for [Add external doc attribute to rustc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44732) or c) use nightly with [rdoc](https://github.com/mgattozzi/rdoc).

Comment: @zrzka Do you want to add that as an answer? You could just refer to the existing answer regarding HTML and provide a tiny example of how to use this external doc attribute. That would be neat :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTML

As already answered by Francis, you have to use HTML if you'd like to keep short lines. `rustdoc` utilizes [pulldown-cmark](https://github.com/raphlinus/pulldown-cmark) and there's no support for what you want.

### Include external documentation

#### nightly & doc

[Tracking issue: rfc 1990 - add external doc attribute to rustc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44732). In case of `nightly` toolchain, you can enable `external_doc` feature and include external Markdown files with `#[doc(include = "../some/path")]`.

One thing to note - no matter in what module you will use `#[doc(include = "...")]`, the path is **always** relative to the crate root (`lib.rs`, `main.rs`, ...).

Example:

```
.
|____Cargo.toml
|____Cargo.lock
|____doc
| |____foo-bar-bar.md
|____src
| |____main-hallo.md
| |____foo
| | |____mod.rs
| | |____bar.rs
| |____main.rs
```

`src/main.rs`:

```
#![feature(external_doc)]

pub mod foo;

#[doc(include = "main-hallo.md")]
pub fn hallo() {}

fn main() {}
```

`src/foo/bar.rs`:

```
#[doc(include = "../doc/foo-bar-bar.md")]
pub struct Bar;
```

You can keep separate Markdown documentation in the `src/` folder, you can have it in a separate folder like `doc/`, etc. But the path is always relative to the crate root.

#### nightly & rdoc

There's also [rdoc](https://github.com/mgattozzi/rdoc) compiler plugin (requires `nightly`), which basically does the same thing. How to enable & use it is described in the project [README.md](https://github.com/mgattozzi/rdoc/blob/master/README.md).

#### stable

For stable, I'd do the following:

- documentation in separate Markdown files,
- custom `build.rs` which will scan for `.md` files and outputs them as `.rs` files (same content, just prepend every line with `///` or `//!`),

  - put them in the `std::env::var("OUT_DIR")` folder,
- include them in your source code,

  - via `include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/main-hallo-md.rs"));`.

### rustfmt & nightly

There's `comment_width` option (defaults to `80`) & `wrap_comments` option (defaults to `false`). This helps you to keep comments up to some width. But I tried it with the long Markdown table line and it wrapped it -> broken table. Don't use it.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for exploring all kinds of possible solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Use HTML markup.

```
//! Demonstrating HTML tables.
//!
//! <table>
//!     <thead>
//!         <tr>
//!             <th>Foo</th>
//!             <th>Bar</th>
//!             <th>Baz</th>
//!             <th>Quux</th>
//!         </tr>
//!     </thead>
//!     <tbody>
//!         <tr>
//!             <td>Hail the turbofish <code>::&lt;></code></td>
//!             <td>Ferris for president </td>
//!             <td>
//!                 I can't think of any
//!                 more "funny" things
//!             </td>
//!             <td>oopsie</td>
//!         </tr>
//!     </tbody>
//! </table>
```